# pause between background pic and first textView

Tags: android

i'm a new android developer, writing my first app. i want to bring up before the background pic and after a few seconds the first textView. is possible do something like this? and what methods should i use?

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to a "splash screen"? Plenty of examples available if you do a search (and arguments [when](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Reinforcing) ([not](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html)) to use one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you want to show your image and after few seconds you want to show your textview. 
1 - Make textview visibility in visible by using android:visibility="invisible"
2 - For this you will have to load the image in OnCreate method.
3 - Create a thread and in that thread make your textview visible after delay

```
 Handler h = new Handler();

         h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


                @Override
                public void run()
                {  
                 textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }, 3000); //3000 = 3sec
```

Comment: you understand right and it works. i can use this way to show also editTexts and buttons after few seconds? thank you for your help

Comment: Ok i just did the same thing for editTexts and buttons, but how can i set a different time? for example i want to set visible 3 textviews after 3 seconds, and otherthings after 5 seconds. should i create an another postDealyed?

Comment: you will have to create 2 different Handlers with different times.

Comment: last thing. is possible in this way to show something after an action? to let you understand, in an activity i have 4 buttons, can i show the second one after i click on the first one and return in the button's activity?

Comment: Yes you can. For example if you want to show a textview on a button's click then do something like this      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   });